# Dreamweaver not auto indenting

Tags: format, dreamweaver, indentation

I recently started to use dreamweaver and i like it so far. I only got one problem with it. 
I saw on youtube videos that when somebody types the code, after pressing enter dreamweaver automatically indents the code. The problem is, is that my dreamweaver doesnt do this for me.

I searched every forum, recreated my config folder and rechecked al the preferences (preferences -> format code) and enabled the auto indent in the code view options but nothing works.

Instead of getting this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

i get this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

anbody has the same problem?

I know you can set the indentation with specific tags, but html know allot of tags so i would be a pain if i had to do it one by one.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit > Preferences > Code Format

Check the Indent checkbox.

Comment: Unhelpful. It's enabled by default but the problem persists.